# How does this Update Statement work?

Tags: mysql, sql

I had a coworker today write a improperly written SQL update.

```
UPDATE table SET column  = 'change'
WHERE id = 2401 OR 2402 OR 2403 OR 2404 OR 2405 OR 2406;


Query OK, 264 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Rows matched: 9997 Changed: 264  Warnings: 0
```

Why would this work?

I thought at most it would update 1 row with ID being unique. and 2402 and 2403....etc not being matched against anything.

Comment: It updated each row in the table, as MySQL interpreted each ID from 2402 as true.  `where ID=2401 OR True OR True OR True OR True;`

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of MySQL which instead of rejecting incorrect SQL tries to guess what you meant to make your life easier. I consider this a bug in MySQL - the SQL syntax is plain wrong and shouldn't work in the first place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What happened is `OR 2402` was treated as a true value, as if you put `1 = 1` or another condition that always returns true. Your query was read by MySQL as

```
UPDATE table SET column  = 'change'
WHERE id = 2401 OR true OR true OR true OR true OR true;
```

Answer (score 2):

That statement is wrong and would update all your records.  The
correct query is:

```
UPDATE table 
SET column  = 'change'
WHERE id = 2401 OR id= 2402 OR id=2403 OR id=2404 OR id=2405 OR id=2406;
```

or better:

```
UPDATE table 
SET column  = 'change'
WHERE id IN (2401,2402,2403,2404,2405,2406);
```

your original query updates record whose id is 2401 and any other row for which holds that 2042 is "true" which it is for all (as 2042 isn't 0 or false)

Comment: I understand that it was wrong I want to know why it did what it did.

Comment: Is it possible that some of other rows already had "change" as column value? Then it would not be updated, and it would lead to "changed" value lower than total rows count.

Comment: @ejzy that was exactly it most rows were listed as "change" the only rows that were not were the 264 that were changed.